# Threading in c#?

Tags: c#

```
class Form1
{ 
    private void sendemail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        totalproxy=10;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalproxy; i++)
        {
            ThreadStart ts1 = new ThreadStart(sendmail());
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(ts1);
            thread1.Start();
            while (thread1.IsAlive) ;
        }            

    }

    public void sendmail()
    {
        //some code goes here
    }
}
```

is gives me an error that method name expected here

```
new ThreadStart(xxxxx);
```

but `sendmail()` is already written there.

Comment: you can use an AutoResetEvent instead of  the 'while (thread1.IsAlive) '

Comment: I suggest ( if you are using .NET 4.0+ ) to use the TPL ( Task Parallel Library ) since it is easier to use and syncronize parallel Tasks. You can read more about it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 8):

replace

```
new ThreadStart(sendmail());
```

with

```
new ThreadStart(sendmail);
```

since you don't want to CALL a method but give the method delegate to the thread

Comment: I have made an windows application for sending emails in c# (.net). But it starts to hangs and show not responding 

There is one main function which is in the test file here http://what-isonlinebanking.com/problem.txt

Please have a look and give some suggestion that how can I avoid hanging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadStart needs a delegate ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.80).aspx ) which is a function address, exactly like the address of another variable.

In your code, you USE sendmail instead of just giving its address by its name `ThreadStart ts1 = new ThreadStart(sendmail);`